# How do I put a lower seat clamp on my Alinker walking aid?

Tags: maintenance, seatpost, balance-bike

I have a walking aid called an **Alinker** http://www.thealinker.com/

It looks like a bicycle but it has no pedals and any bike shop can service it.

My issue is the seat it's a older style so has 2 bolts under the seat  mounted on the rails and I accidentally unscrewed all the bolts and the triangle shaped piece came out. I have the piece flipped upwards and its on the bottom of the rails. Can anyone here explain how to put this piece in the correct way. I am attaching a picture of my Alinker and the part in question.

I don't know much about bikes so please explain in easy terms.

[image]

[image: image of a Alinker walking bike - cropped]

[image: OP's pic of their walker]

[image: From other answer]

Comment: We can't see your picture of the bike, and newer models appear to have a different seat clamp scheme.

Comment: You appear to have a clamp similar to this one: https://www.performancebike.com/thomson-elite-seatpost-saddle-clamp-assembly-black-for-oversize-rails-sp-h005-bk/p324335

Comment: Yes exactly!! I am talking about the middle triangular shaped piece.. I am curious how that middle piece goes!! I assume it goes upwards on the bottom of the seat post

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the photos on thealinker.com, the current clamp is a bit like the one in the photo below that I've borrowed to show a close up of something I think is similar..

The plate you have shown a photo of looks to me like one which fits in a dip in the top of the seat post and the two grooves face up with the saddle rails in. Then a second piece with two threaded holes in sits on top of the rails, with the two bolts through, clamping everything together.

The part in question should be flipped up so that the two grooves on the ends are running fore/aft and are able to support the saddle rails, while the large curve drops into the matching curve of the seatpost

Figuring out where the parts go is the first puzzle, the second is convincing them to go where you want them to! Takes a bit of patience and time sometimes.

[image]

photo from forums.mtbr.com

[image]
photo from www.thealinker.com

Comment: Yes you are right about the plate.. I just wasn't sure what way it went.. I currently have it flipped upwards but curious if it actually had a right way of going in not the way in the picture.. I know what part goes where just the bottom piece I showed in the post went..

Comment: @MacaulayDow yes it has to go one way only, I've edited my answer to confirm, but it sounds like you have it the correct way.

Comment: Ok I wasn't sure ..

Comment: Does it matter what side is which way ??

Comment: @MacaulayDow As long as the grooves for the saddle rails are facing up and pointing forwards, it doesn't matter is one groove is on the left and the other on the right, or vice versa, it has a line of symmetry

Comment: Does it matter what side is which and does the lower seat clamp and the top go in any section of the seat or does it just go in the middle.. After putting it back together I realized that my seat swivels too much does that mean I have to tighten the seat binder bolt??

Comment: How do you know if the lower seat plate is pointing forward?? Or does it not matter??

Comment: Sorry pointing forwards was misleading, I just mean aligned with the rails. The seat can be positioned fore and aft in the clamp, and the clamp will tilt up and down too, putting the saddle in the middle and level with the ground is a good start, but you can adjust it for your own use. The two bolts should be nice and tight to hold the saddle, goodandtight, then if the whole seat post swivels then the stem binder bolt will need tightening, but more carefully with less force than the saddle because it is clamping a tube.

Answer (score 3):

OK, now I see what you're talking about.  I suspect the piece you have should go beneath the seat rails, with the cylindrical section pointing down and nesting in a matching half-cylinder depression in the base of the assembly.  The two ends of the piece have grooves (on the opposite side from the cylindrical face) that should accept the rails from the seat.

Then the top piece is bolted down over the rails (with bolts from the bottom).

The purpose of the cylindrical side of the piece you're wondering about is so that that piece can "rock" in the "cradle" created by the base, allowing forward/backward tilt of the seat to be adjusted.

Comment: Yes exactly! So how does that piece go besides flipping it upwards

Answer (score 2):

This is the best image I can find of the seatpost area for an older style (I don't understand how it's folded up):

(Oops, not an image of a Alinker)

This is the seatpost area of what I believe is the newer tricycle style:
[image]

OK, and I finally deciphered your original question (I think).  You're talking about the clamp that holds the seat to the seatpost.  There are several different variations of these.  Google "bicycle saddle clamp".

Here's an image of a similar clamp installed:
[image]

The problem is that there are a dozen different ways that the saddle clamp may attach to vertical seatpost, and we can't tell from the images what technique is being used.

Comment: What on earth is going on in that first photo? This appears to be the construction of the frame, not a folded position, but I can't figure out why it would be useful to have the handlebars below and behind the seat, nor how you would be able to turn the crank with the handlebars anywhere but straight forward (backward?). Definitely looks like a trick and not something that would assist anyone in doing anything.

Comment: @IanMacDonald - Yeah, I don't know.  When I first grabbed the image off of Google I didn't notice that it was kind of screwed up, so I don't know if it's real or some sort of joke.

Comment: Found it.  It's not a Alinker, but a Halbrad, and not a walking bike, but a really odd sort of stunt bike: https://www.gadgenda.com/halbrad-the-half-wheel-bike  (I'll remove the image)

Comment: Woah that's wild.

Comment: @MacaulayDow - Good luck!

Comment: I added a picture of the seat up close.. It's not my Instagram but it's the closest thing I could find